# Stuck with styling dropdown in grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

New to css grid here. I'm trying to achieve this layout - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohyqo.jpg

I'm stuck at the dropdown menus. Not sure how to lay it out 2 columns 3 rows

Forgot to mention, I want to make it single column when I shrink browser, like when we're viewing it on phones. I'd like it to look like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LClI3.jpg

Here's my  code - https://codepen.io/v1rt/pen/KKyPXNw

```css
/* Typography imported from Google Fonts */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Source+Sans+Pro:200,400');
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

p,
a {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}


/* Generic styles */

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  /* Photo by mnm.all on Unsplash */
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518176258769-f227c798150e') center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  /* grid styles */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
}

.midmenu {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section class="top"></section>
  <section class="midmenu">
    <SELECT name="s1">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT name="s2">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT name="s3">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT name="s4">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT name="s5">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT name="s6">
      <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      <option value='green'>Green</option>
      <option value='red'>Red</option>
      <option value='yellow'>Yelllow</option>
      <option value='' selected>Select a Color </option>
      <option value='white'>White</option>
    </SELECT>
  </section>
  <section class="bottom"></section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use grid by adding following property to your `midmenu class`-**

```css
.midmenu {
  padding: 20px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
}
```

Comment: grid-template-columns property specifies the number (and the widths) of columns in a grid layout. 2 times auto auto creates 2 grid of equal sizes here

Comment: You can also accept my answer it will be helpful as well as for other developers.

Comment: I updated my main post. How to make it like this when browser width is reduced?  https://imgur.com/a/zmn3DZo

Comment: @devwannabe you can achieve this by just setting the grid-template-columns value to auto(only one time). This will create 1 column in each row. You can read more about grid at- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Yep, I got it working the other day. Yes, that's what I did. :)